# RecyclerView or Glide doesn't update image when the image is overwritten

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-glide

I use Glide in `onBindViewHolder()` method in an adapter extended from `RecyclerView.Adapter` as follows:

```
Glide.with(context)
    .load(imagePath)
    .override(500, 500)
    .crossFade()
    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.RESULT)
    .into(((MyItemHolder) holder).imageView);
```

Then, I do cropping in one of the images that are given as data to the adapter. After cropping image, I overwrite the image file, i.e., I save the edited image with the same filename. So the `imagePath` stays the same whereas the image has changed. However, this change isn't being reflected in the RecyclerView even with a separate `notifyDataSetChanged()` call. The change reflected if I save the edited image with a different filename.

Is there any way to achieve detection of the image content change while keeping filename same?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason this is happening is because `Glide` is caching the image and as the path is same so it will not get to know about the change. For this to work you need to change the caching strategy and skip the memory cache like this:

```
Glide.with(context)
    .load(imagePath)
    .override(500, 500)
    .crossFade()
    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
    .skipMemoryCache(true)
    .into(((MyItemHolder) holder).imageView);
```

Now the image will not get cached and the image will get updated.

Comment: Worth noting that there is performance hit for bypassing these strategies - but this answer is 100% correct.

Comment: @MarkKeen agreed but this is the only way to solve the problem because the cache key is saved according to the URL (imagePath in the above case), so unless the imagePath changes, Glide will not update the cache even if the contents stored at the path changes

Comment: I have tried `DiskCacheStrategy.NONE` and it didn't work. I now added `skipMemoryCache(true)` part and it is working. I am worried about performance so I will use different filename, but this seems to be the only way.

Comment: @SudhanshuVohra I know - I agreed with your solution, and upvoted! :) . My comment was purely for the OP to be aware of.

Comment: your solution is correct but reloads whole recyclerveiw when call notifyDataSetChanged();  is there any other solution to refresh glide?